# Rails find condition delete first 2 symbols from field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have such AR code:

```
@types = Type.find(:all, 
             :conditions => { :TYP_MOD_ID => params[:models],
                              :TYP_PCON_START => params[:year] }, 
             :order => "TYP_HP_FROM")
```

but how can i do that i see `TYP_PCON_START` without first 2 symbols and compare? 
for example `:TYP_PCON_START.to_s[4...6]`

Also i need to compare not =, but >= > condition. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `find`. Also i didn't understand what you mean by `how can i do that i see TYP_PCON_START without first 2 symbols and compare?`.

```
@types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ? AND substring(TYP_PCON_START FROM 4 to 6) >= ?", 
  params[:models], params[:year]).order("TYP_HP_FROM")
```

Comment: i mean some operating with string: for example in db i have 062006, but i want to be compared only 2006 value

Comment: Oh, just use the substring method on the params, i will edit the answer.

Comment: no no! data from bd must be shrinked... TYP_PCON_START (0..4)  as you see, i write it in question

Comment: If you are using `PostgreSQL` you can use the `substring` function like this: `substring(TYP_PCON_START from 4 to 6) >= ?`. Don't know about others RDBMS though.

Comment: Also i believe you shouldn't use `>=` for strings. =]

Comment: you are right) to_s is bad idea for int) but how to do for mysql?

Comment: done so:     @types = Type.where("TYP_MOD_ID = ? AND (SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_START,1,4) <= ?) AND (SUBSTRING(TYP_PCON_END,1,4) >= ?) AND TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID = ? ", params[:models], params[:year], params[:year], params[:fueltype]).order("TYP_HP_FROM")